# Laravel. Как работают неймспейсы в файлах фреймворка? Я не могу найти куда они ссылаются и откуда что грузят

Tags: laravel, namespace

Возьмем, к примеру, этот файл

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php
```

В нем мы видим следующее:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter as EncrypterContract;
```

Откуда грузится класс **Closure**? Я не вижу файла **Closure.php** ни в этой же папке, ни в где-либо рядом, ни в корне.
Тоже самое и с **Symfony\Component**. В древе файлов даже структуры такой нет.

Может кто-нибудь объяснить как оно работает?

Comment: [Класс Closure](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.closure.php). На счет `Symfony\Component` это компонент Symfony который используется в Laravel, он в свою очередь лежит в `vendor\symfony\component`. Вы как их искали? Установите себе или IDE или PHP IntelliSense плагин в Ваш редактор кода. Обычно внутрь таких компонентов редиректит по клику с зажатым cmd/ctrl.

Comment: Так в том-то и дело, что нет такой папки в вендоре и вообще нигде нет. Посмотрите https://ibb.co/k0gc7qC

Comment: Посмотрите в `vendor\symfony\http-foundation`, я ошибся с расположением. Ну и Вы пробовали на него кликнуть с зажатым ctrl?

Comment: Да, попробовал ткнуть на Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie, открылся файл /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Cookie.php А почему неймспейс не соответствует реальному расположению файла?

Comment: Посмотрите в composer.json компонента http-foundation, какой неймспейс там установлен для PSR-4 автозагрузки `"psr-4": { "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\": "" }`. Почему конкретно так с этим компонентом, ответ дать не смогу, видимо есть на это некие причины.

Comment: Да, именно так и указано "psr-4": { "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\": "" }

Comment: Но там везде такое. Возьмем файл `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Env.php` в нем указано `use Dotenv\Repository\Adapter\PutenvAdapter;` которой лежит в `/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Repository/Adapter/PutenvAdapter.php`

Comment: Получается, что это намеренное несоответствие PSR-4?

Comment: так closure это же класс самого языка. Когда мы используем пространство имён при проектировании архитектуры и т.д, Для того чтобы вызвать встроенные классы языка, итераторы например или stdClass мы используем просто use и название (помимо классов тех же пространств имён). Или возможно вы видели такую структуру: \stdClass слеш на конце говорит о том, что ищи всё это на нижнем уровне. По поводу PutenvAdapter...

Comment: Такой принцип построения `namespace` идёт по такой причине: Папка vendor не указывается никогда в пространстве имён, это просто папка которая загружается в autoload.php композером и подключает все библиотеки находящиеся в данной папке. Далее внутри этой папки лежат библиотеки со СВОИМ пространством имён который соответствует psr-4 и своим composer.json файлом. (Почитайте как делаются библиотеки на лару). Далее идёт название автора (vlucas) что просто указывает имя на гитхабе и не является пространством имён. А вот следующая папка уже является первым словом при проектировании пространста и ...

Comment: .... характеризует конкретный пакет (библиотеку) автора. Так как phpdotenv не красиво при пространстве, автор решил сделать так. По сути название библиотеки не всегда соответствует названию пространству имён (то же часто можно увидеть). Далее папка src то же пропускается и прописывается в composer.json файле. А все остальные файлы должны соответствовать psr-4. Что можно и наблюдать. `Dotenv\Repository\Adapter\PutenvAdapter` без vendor автора и src.

Comment: так же и с namespace лары, его не делали как в симфони схожим, а сделали `Illuminate`. Как и писал выше, название пакета может отличаться от namespace root директории

Comment: Спасибо. В целом стало понятнее.